# Evento ShutdownEvent no se ejecuta

Tags: java, quarkus

Que tal buenas noches.

Estoy aprendiendo Quarkus y en su [documentación](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle) explican sobre 2 eventos en particular; *StartupEvent* y *ShutdownEvent*.

Al arrancar la aplicación, en la consola muestra el mensaje del evento *StartupEvent* tal y como se espera pero al finalizar no muestra el mensaje del evento *ShutdownEvent*, a continuación dejo el código y la salida en consola:

```
package org.acme;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;

import io.quarkus.runtime.ShutdownEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifeCycleBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("ListenerBean");

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {

        LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");

    }

    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) {

        LOGGER.info("The application is stopping...");
        
    }

}
```

Salida en consola:

```
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2023-10-06 23:54:00,735 INFO  [ListenerBean] (Quarkus Main Thread) The application is starting...
2023-10-06 23:54:00,832 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.3.3) started in 2.862s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2023-10-06 23:54:00,833 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2023-10-06 23:54:00,834 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy-reactive, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
Run CustomMain method

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Como ya mencione, el mensaje *"The application is starting..."* del evento de inicio si veo que se ejecuta, sin embargo el de termino no, solo acaba en *"Process finished with exit code 130"*

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe esto? He investigado sobre este tema pero no logro dar con una solucion o respuesta concreta, gracias.